# Como colocar icone de voltar em uma toolbar dentro de um fragment que oculta a toolbar principal?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com um problema para colocar o icone de voltar numa toolbar dentro de um fragment que está ocultando a toolbar principal.

Utilizo o android studio, e criei um Navigation Drawer Activity, onde trabalho com fragments para abrir as opções do menu, e que ja tenho uma toolbar fixa para todas as fragments.

E então surgiu um novo problema. Uma das opções eu tentei colocar um Scrolling Activity, e até consegui com sucesso, porém estava tendo duas toolbars como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor ignore as cores, ainda não ajustei o layout.

E então eu consegui ocultar a toolbar principal utilizando:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

E então ficou quase perfeito, desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas agora eu queria colocar um botão de voltar, como neste exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É facil colocar quando abre uma Activity nova, mas nesse caso como é uma toolbar dentro de um fragment que está ocultando outra toolbar, eu não imagino nem um pouco como faz.

Segue o layout dentro da fragment que utilizo.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="br.com.teste.app.MenuPages.FragmentTerms">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_custom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="Declarações Legais" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/terms_text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver. talvez numa gambiarra.

Adicionei um ImageButton com uma seta para voltar.

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_custom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Declarações Legais">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_white" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Pode não ser o melhor método, e nem sei se vai ficar legal em todos os dispositivos, mas por enquanto ta dando certo. Se alguém ainda conhecer outra maneira melhor, por favor eu adoraria conhecer outras soluções.